# Are sulfates or nitrates common ions in biochemistry (specifically of the body)?

Tags: general-biology

It's a rather broad question but something I'm curious about.

I know sulfates tend to be very soluble ions and so don't know nitrates. 
I also know that phosphates are extremely common in biochemistry (e.g. ADP) but they're not very soluble unless they involve group 1 elements, same goes for carbonates. 
I think Carbonates tend to be more common in crustacea, or chicken egg shells. I can't remember if it's found in the Krebb's cycle (don't think so, but maybe in other vitamins?).

Solubility isn't apart of this question, it was just one of the ways I was just trying to pursue an answer. I'm more of a chemist than a biologist...